# Why does RelayCommand<T>.Execute take an object instead of a T?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, relaycommand

This hasn't done anything but cause the need for what would otherwise be unnecessary casting (or rather, caused me to pull down the codebase and make the change myself). Is there a reason for doing this?

References:

[Source on Codeplex](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8ea49c2f278d)

[Blog posting with source](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/sample-code/SilverlightWPFandXAML/76e6b583-edb1-4e23-95f6-7ad8510c0f88/pass-command-parameter-to-relaycommand.aspx)

**Edit**
Here's an example:

```
DoCommand = new RelayCommand<AsyncCallback>((callBack) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("In the Action<AsyncCallback>");
    SomeAsyncFunction((async_result) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In the AsyncCallback");
        callBack.Invoke(new MyAsyncResult(true));
    });
});

DoCommand.Execute((iasyncresult) => Console.WriteLine(iasyncresult.IsCompleted));
//Where MyAsyncResult is a class implement IAsyncResult that sets IsCompleted in the constructor
// This will cause the "cannot cast lambda as object" error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is due to the lambda not being able to be passed as an `object`. Instead try:

```
AsyncCallback callback = (iasyncresult) => Console.WriteLine(iasyncresult.IsCompleted);
DoCommand.Execute(callback);
```

Comment: That does work, and is similar to just casting as an AsyncCallback, but I find the anonymous lambda to be much more readable. Why is this not idiomatic? We nest the callbacks because we have to wait for both a server response and indicate to the parent view that one of its popups has completed the async operation it was set off to do.

Comment: @bearcdp: I was driving at your use of a lambda as a parameter to an `ICommand`. Why use `ICommand` if its not being wired up as part of your XAML?

Comment: It is wired up to XAML, just figured it'd be simplest to present it as pure C# for the toy example. It's triggered by a button press, but then that ICommand needs to kick off some async operations and perform some other operations after they're complete.

Comment: @bearcdp: would it make sense to expose the `AsyncCallback` as a property on your `ViewModel` and have `<Button Command="{Binding DoCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Callback}" />`?

Comment: @sixlettervariables: That's what we've done in other cases, but unfortunately it wouldn't quite work in this one. We're doing some UI effects and are trying to avoid polluting the ViewModel with UI logic.

Comment: @bearcdp: understood. Your likely answer then is you won't find a way to implicitly convert a lambda to an object. You'll have to store it in a delegate first. My group takes a looser look at view models and allows anything which helps the model interoperate with the view (including some UI logic where necessary).

Comment: @sixlettervariables: We may try that out in a future revision then. We're still relatively new with MVVM and just trying to keep our classes lean and our architecture sane. Thank you very much for your insight!

Comment: @bearcdp: we've been at it for a few years now (since WPF's inception) and I can tell you we still feel like we're just getting started.

Answer (score 6):

Because [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx) is not generic.  A generic implementation of **ICommand** must cast from the interface, handle invalid casts, and forward the cast instance to the generic methods.